# inject bytecode into java.lang.StringBuilder

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation

I'm doing some experiment with StringBuilder, and I intend to inject some bytecode into the class using ASM. But I could not find the location of the class. Can anyone point out the location of this class ?

bhm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is packaged into in rt.jar in your JDK installation. Isn't it in yours?